# Using javascript to change include path

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using this code to change the include path with javascript:

```
$('#actionLink').attr('href', $('#actionLink').attr('href')  + '?page=welcome');


 switch($_GET['page'])) {
     case 'welcome':
         include 'section/welcome.html';
         break;
     case 'nda':
         include 'section/nda.html';
         break;
 }
```

But how do this using a submitbutton?

Comment: What is `#actionLink`, and how do you get the page containing the PHP includes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the page *URL* names on the buttons:

```
<form method="get" action="<this page's address>">
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="page1" />
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="page2" />
</form>
```

Or, to show other text there:

```
<form method="get" action="<this page's address>">
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Page 1 button text" onclick="this.value='page1'" />
    <input type="submit" name="page" value="Page 2 button text" onclick="this.value='page2'" />
</form>
```

Or lastly, with a hidden field & jQuery:

```
<form method="get" action="<this page's address>">
    <input type="submit" value="Page 1 button text" onclick="$('#hidden').val('page1')" />
    <input type="submit" value="Page 2 button text" onclick="$('#hidden').val('page2')" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" id="hidden" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').onclick(function() {
$(location).attr('href', 'www.example.com'); //redirect to www.example.com
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it in HTML.

```
 <form method="GET" action="?page=whatever">
     <input type="submit" value="Click Me!" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourpage.php">
     ....
     <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="welcome">
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>

// $_REQUEST works for both $_GET and $_POST
switch($_REQUEST['page'])) {
     case 'welcome':
         include 'section/welcome.html';
         break;
     case 'nda':
         include 'section/nda.html';
         break;
 }
```

I hope this can be of some help.